# Why does the electric displacement vector $D$ have the same unit of charge density?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dimensional-analysis, dielectric, si-units

I was in doubt about electric displacement, after some time I tried to find the unit of $D$ which is $Cm^{-2}$. Why?

Comment: Because of how $\mathbf{D}$ is defined in SI units. Don't think of it as a surface charge density. Think $q/r^2$.

Comment: But what is the physical significance of electric displacement?

Comment: An $\mathbf{E}$ field applied to matter (as opposed to vacuum) polarizes the atoms in the matter. This creates an *additional* electric field. The $\mathbf{D}$ field takes both into account.

Comment: Is this $E$ external or internal electric field produced due to Polarization?And how $D$ field takes both into account?

Comment: Actually, I think it is $\mathbf{E}$ that includes both. $\mathbf{D}$ is the part that doesn’t include the field from the polarized atoms. Sorry for the confusion. I am better at thinking about fields in vacuum than in matter.

Comment: I am very confused.May you give me some reference from where I can learn about it?

Comment: Well, if you are unhappy with your textbook, I’m not sure that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field) will seem more helpful.

Comment: The various answers to [this PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/difference-between-electric-field-mathbf-e-and-electric-displacement-field) may be useful.

Comment: $\nabla \cdot \vec D = \rho$ where $\rho$ is the volume charge density.